# How to print or export to a file values of a tensor while training with Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am having a hard time with trying to display or export to a file the values contained in a tensor while keras is training.

I use tensorflow as backend.

I need it for debug purpose in my custom loss function I passed to my model.compile() method. 
Nothing I tried worked until now (tf.print, keras.backend.print_tensor, ...)

I am really stuck because of that.

Is it even possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: Have a look at [this site](https://medium.com/chakki/debug-keras-models-with-tensorflow-debugger-2b68b8e38370), I think that will help you :)

Comment: thanks ! it was useful